# How to parse changed json data in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

[image: Screenshot of the ouput]

I want to display the json keys with different names. 
Below are the months number which I want to display as jan, feb, mar... etc.

My attempt is as follows.

My result is 1, 2, 3, 4... and not as jan, feb, mar...

What am I doing wrong?
PS: using handlebars.js

My HTML code:

```
{{#each this}}
   <th style="white-space: nowrap;">{{@key}}</th>
{{/each}}
```

My JSON code:

```
"PaymentProfile":{  
                     "2017":{  
                        "1":"C",
                        "2":"C",
                        "3":"C",
                        "4":"C",
                        "5":"C",
                        "6":"C",
                        "7":"C",
                        "8":" ",
                        "9":" ",
                        "10":" ",
                        "11":" ",
                        "12":" "
                     },
```

My javascript:

```
var months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var mortgagePath=data.TradeLine['Mortgage Accounts']['0'].PaymentProfile;
                    $.each(mortgagePath,function(k,v){
                        console.log("year is"+k)
                        $.each(v, function(k1,v1){
                           // k1= months[k1];
                           console.log("month is "+months[k1-1]);
                           console.log("status is "+v1)
                        })
                    });
```

Comment: what is value from this line `console.log("month is "+months[k1-1]);`

Comment: your jquery code works for me i am getting the month names in console. what is your error?

Comment: @Niladri 
year is2015
 month is Jan
 status is  
month is Feb
 status is  
 month is Mar ... and so on..

Comment: i am not getting proper output.. i am getting output as 1,2,3.. 
i want to know how can i display jan feb mar.. instead of 1 ,2 ,3
i'll post screenshot if you still not getting

Comment: do you mean in handle bars ? can you try with `{{#each 2017}}
   <th style="white-space: nowrap;">{{this}}</th>
{{/each}}`

Comment: @Niladri - i added the screenshot. 
i tried  {{this}} but it's not working. i am getting output as value i.e status "C" and not the keys.

Comment: `@key` is going to be the value of the key in the hash, so 1-12 when you are going over the months. Youll need to make a helper/computed property, or reorganize the data appropriately first.

Comment: @prodigitalson can you please me out with the helper ?
how can i do that ?

Comment: @JSnewbie what is the name of the root object you are iterating? i can only see `this`

Comment: @Niladri iterating is proper path i.e from data through PaymentProfile

Comment: @JSnewbie pls check my answer. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the below code it works for me . you have to register a helper to display a computed property as `monthname` using the `@key`

in your JS file add

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('monthName', function(key) {
  return months[key-1]; 
//months is the array which contains the name of months
});
```

in your template change  like below

```
{{#each this}}
   <th style="white-space: nowrap;">{{monthName @key}}</th>
{{/each}}
```

Here is a link to a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/az5skvfm/2/

Comment: @JSnewbie can you please mark this answer so that others can benefit

Comment: i would like to do so but it's restricting me due to reputation less than 15. can you help me in gaining reputation ?

Comment: ok you have to be active and gain reputation, any other moderators can accept this as answer i think.

Comment: @JSnewbie You should be able to accept the answer. There is a grey checkmark near the vote, click it to turn it green.